# VS2013: Compiling Shaders with Shader Model 5.0

Tags: visual-studio-2013, shader, hlsl

When I try to compile two HLSL files included in my project, the compilation fails with an error:

> Error error X4502: invalid vs_2_0 input semantic 'INSTANCE'

However, I notice it's trying to use shader model 2.0; when I'm trying to use 5.0:

[image: Shader Model 5.0 Selected in Project Property Pages]

Why is the shader compiler trying to use the 2.0 model when I've told VS to use 5.0? Or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is set the "Shader Type" attribute to the correct type of shader you're trying to compile. Then the issue should go away.